# How to deal with a conditional binomial question involving coin flips?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence of fair coin flips. At each round, it is either Heads, which we denote by $H$, or tails, which we denote as $T$. Now, at the end of $N$ flips, which is assumed to be a random variable, we would like to find the probability of Heads being equal to $k$. Suppose for concreteness that the number of flips we do is $1000$, then the statement I am interested in computing is:

$$
P(H=k|N=1000)
$$

Now, if we let $Z_i$ be a sequence of iid Bernoulli random variables with probability parameter $p = \frac{1}{2}$, then we have that we can write:

$$
H = \sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_i
$$

and that $H+T = N$.

Right off the bat, my intuition is that $P(H=k|N=1000) \sim Bin(1000,\frac{1}{2})$.

However, for my own understanding and in trying to formally "show" this intution, I'm try to calculate the above conditional explicitly, though I run into problems. That is:

$$
P(H=k|N=1000) = \frac{P(H=k,N=1000) }{P(N=1000) }
$$

I am not sure how to calculate the numerator. I am not sure how to calculate $P(H=k,N=1000)$. It seem to be the same as the binomial case. Is there a very explicit way to write this?

Comment: The remark about the conditional probability is correct. If then you want to find the probability of $k$ heads, you can use the law of total probability. That's where the distribution of $N$ comes in.

Answer (score 1):

By definition: The count of successes in a sequence of $N$ iid Bernoulli events with success rate $1/2$ *is* a random variable with a Binomial Distribution; $\mathcal{Bin}(N, 1/2)$.   Of course, when $N$ is itself a random variable, this will be a conditional distribution.

This model matches the given scenario for $H$, the count of "head" in a sequence of $N$ iid fair coin tosses where $N$ is a random variable (presumably with a discrete positive integer support).   Thus:

$$H\mid N ~\sim ~\mathcal{Bin}(N, 1/2) \\ \mathsf P(H=k\mid N=n)~=~\dbinom{n}{k}\dfrac 1{2^n}\;\Big[k\in\{0,...,n\}, n\in \{0,1,...\}\Big]$$

That is all that is required.

---

> Is it possible to explicitly calculate $H,N$ without directly resorting to the conditional?

It *may* be possible, if we have sufficient details about the distribution of $N$.

For instance, let us suppose we are told that the count $N$ is Poisson Distributed with a rate of $\lambda$.   Knowing that thence we could immediately assert, because of the nature of events in a Poisson Process, that the counts $H$ and $T$ would each be independently Poisson Distributed with a rate of $\lambda/2$.   Then we could use this to evaluate the joint porbaility of $H, N$ as : $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(H=k, N=n) ~=~ & \mathsf P(H=k)~\mathsf P( T=n-k) \\[1ex] ~=~ & \dfrac{(\lambda/2)^k\mathsf e^{-\lambda/2}}{k!}\cdot\dfrac{(\lambda/2)^{n-k}\mathsf e^{-\lambda/2}}{(n-k)!} \\[1ex] ~=~ & \dfrac{(\lambda/2)^n\mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{k!(n-k)!}\end{align}$$

---

Indeed, we confirm that : $~\mathsf P(H=h\mid N=n)~\mathsf P(N=n) ~=~ \dfrac{n!}{h!(n-h)!}\dfrac 1{2^n}\cdot\dfrac{\lambda^n\mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{n!}$

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly calculate $H, N$ without directly resorting to the conditional? Thanks!

Comment: @user136503 Possibly, *if* we know something about how $N$ is distributed.

Comment: Thanks, just one thing I am not so clear about, above in your example how do we know that $H$ is Poisson distributed?

Comment: @user13503 $N$ is the count of Poisson events arriving in the interval at rate $\lambda$.  For each such event there is a probability $1/2$ that it will be a head; the count of these is $H$.  Thus $H$ is the count of Poisson events arriving in the interval at rate $\lambda/2$.